# Android: How to save instance of the activity on screen orientation change? I use objects, not just simple variables

Tags: android, screen, orientation, instance, save

I have a problem with saving an instance on screen orientation change. I have an array with a specific structure:

```
private ArrayList <MyObject> myArr;
```

And this sctructure is:

```
public MyObject{
    public variable1;
    //..... many variables here and one array :)
}
```

I need to save "myArr" array. How can I save this "variable"?

Comment: Have You tried to implement and use Parcelable?

Comment: I can implement Parcelable interface to my class, but I can't imagine how I will save my array of such classes into the instance-Bundle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, instance should be saved, using the way, described in [Android Activity API Ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges): you need to use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`. Also, You can just set  `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your manifest for an activity to prevent it's recreation (so where won't be any need for state saving presented).

To save objects from the question in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` to the Bundle:

- Implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) by `MyObject` (e.g. example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104508/parcelable-class?rq=1) etc.)
- Put ArrayList in the bundle by [putParcelableArrayList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29) in `onSaveInstanceState()` and get back by [getParcelableArrayList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String%29v) in `onCreate()` after rotation;